# How to determine whether a wavefunction is an acceptable quantum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

My books is asking me to find out if the wavefunctions that are in the exercise are acceptable as state function in a certain interval, like from 0 to $\infty$.
Should i just look to square up the function and see if it's possible to find out the normalization constant or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 main conditions that we need for a function to be a valid wave function.

1. The wave function must be single valued. This guarantees that the wave function returns a single value for the probability for any state. This will be automatically true for any valid mathematical function since this is a condition on functions from mathematical analysis.
2. As you said the wave function must be square integrable. By imposing this condition, we are assured that the wave function is normalizeable and thereforce can have a meaningful probability distribution. To have a valid probability density, the integral over all space needs to equal 1. A consequence of this is that the wave function must go to $0$ at $\pm \infty$.
3. The wave function must be continuous everywhere. If this was not true then the momentum of the system, which is found from the first order derivative in space would go to $\infty$ which is not a physically realizeable system.
4. The first order derivatives of any quantity must be continuous. This must be true from following the same reasoning as (3) st the second derivatives are defined (do not go to $\infty$). For example, if this was not guaranteed, then we may find that the second derivative in the calculation of energy goes to $\infty$.

So to summarize, assuming that you have proper mathematical functions you will be good for (1). Then you must check the function is square integrable, continuous and $\mathrm{C}^1$ (all first order derivatives exist. Upon showing these conditions, you know that you have a wave function that does not break any conditions to be physically realizeable.

Many textbooks gloss over (1), (3), (4) and focus only on the square integrable condition but it is important to understand the physical motivations for all of these conditions to truly ensure that the wave functions behave correctly to be physical.

Comment: Thank you  Fhorrobin.So,if i have a wave function and calculate it's limit at infty and check that it's not equal zero,can i say that it's not acceptable without integrating?

Comment: Given conditions (3) and (4) we can indeed say that the function must go to zero at infinities. There are some "pathelogical" functions that do not have this behavior but they are either formed from discontinuities (breaks 3) or spikes (breaks 4) so we do not worry about them if you know (3) and (4) hold. Not that the converse is not true however. You cannot say a function is square integrable if it goes to 0 at both infinities. You must explicitly check the integration to show the condition holds.

Comment: It's probably worth making a specific note that commonly used example problems (i.e. the infinite square well) require relaxing requirement (4). You *could* then go on to discuss the evolution of the solution in $\lim_{V \to \infty}$ in terms of the radius of curvature near the boundary getting steadily smaller until we can treat it as abrupt for very high potentials, while remaining physically reasonable.

Comment: This probably isn't relevant to the original question but (1) can be relaxed somewhat. You can have single valuedness up to a phase under certain conditions. For instance a wavefunction in the presence of a magnetic monopole.

Comment: I guess the important thing to note is that though there are many physical scenarios where we can justify relaxing the rules, in general the above rules must hold on the domain of interest for a general function to potentially be a physically valid wave funtion.

Comment: Continuity and differentiability are not physical conditions for the wavefunction. Only weak differentiability (in the sobolev sense) is required for a wavefunction to have finite average momentum.

Comment: @fhorrobin Is there a case that a function meet all these requirements but is not a valid wavefunction?